# Remove dups on one side but not on the other in SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, duplicates

**code updated:**
Added [score] column to #left table. The join must pull student name *and* score from #left table. Any one score is fine but it should not pull duplicate student_id. I am thinking cursor can do it?

---

I am running this report. The problem is similar to the the script that I created. To sum up, I have two tables lets call it #left and #right. The #right table is the key one which contains the amount. But the #left table contains the agent name which I must retrieve too.

```
create table #left (
id int not null primary key identity,
student_id int, name varchar(20),score int)

insert into #left values( 1, 'James',10)
insert into #left values( 2, 'Parker',20)
insert into #left values( 3, 'Smith',30)
insert into #left values( 4, 'Rog',40)
insert into #left values( 1, 'James',50)
insert into #left values( 2, 'Parker',60)

create table #right (
id int not null primary key identity,
student_id int,
amount decimal(5,2)
)

insert into #right values (1,5.25)
insert into #right values (3,7.25)
insert into #right values (4,3.25)
insert into #right values (1,5.25)
```

The problem here is I want to join the two tables on student_id but as you can see #left table contains James and Parker 2 times with the same id. Lets assume this was database mistake.

A similar problem can exists in the #right table. But that is not a mistake. It simply means the #left student was associated with two payments (even if the two payments are the same).

**I want to remove dups from #left table and keep the dups in the #right table.**

I came up with this query, which works

```
/* query 1 */
select student_id, amount from #right R
where exists
(
select student_id from #left L
where R.student_id = L.student_id
);
```

**But the problem here is I also need to pull the student name** from the other table. Is there a way to do it. It can be any syntax but efficient query is desirable.

Comment: If your problem has changed after people have solved your original question, don't change the question. Ask a new one, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

**Solution to the original problem**

Where #left table looked like this

```
create table #left (
id int not null primary key identity,
student_id int, name varchar(20))

insert into #left values( 1, 'James')
insert into #left values( 2, 'Parker')
insert into #left values( 3, 'Smith')
insert into #left values( 4, 'Rog')
insert into #left values( 1, 'James')
insert into #left values( 2, 'Parker')
```

**Query: 1**

```
SELECT A.student_id, A.amount, B.name
FROM #right A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT student_id, name FROM #left) B
ON A.student_id = B.student_id
```

**UPDATED to the modified criteria** Well, if *any score* is fine, then you can do this:

**Query: 2**

```
SELECT A.student_id, A.amount, B.name, B.score
FROM #right A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT student_id, name, MIN(score) score
            FROM #left
            group by student_id, name) B
ON A.student_id = B.student_id
```

Comment: this works but I think I am gonna modify my model here. If I use distinct in my actual problem, it contains a field that is different and therefore pulls more records. I will update my question. +1 so far :)

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - Ok, then I guess I'll have to wait for you to update your post

Comment: I basically need a logic like this: I am traversing through #right table and if a record exist in #left table based on student_id, then I include some fields from #left table as well to complete my query.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - And that is what the answer I posted is doing. If you want something different, then post your expected data as an example, so we can help you

Comment: updated the code.I thinking cursor can do it? You may post a second answer as this one correctly fixed the first problem.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: also consider if you should ask another, *correct* question...

Comment: @gbn, certainly will, if this question was not addressed. Will revert this one to the older version.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - Ok, I updated my answer now. And no, you don't need a cursor for this

Comment: btw I came up with a cursor solution as my original problem was more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If there can exist students with no payments (no rows in #right table), you should start from the #left table I think with joining. For avoiding duplicate student rows you could use distinct as already suggested or aggregate functions like group by.

Some untested code for my idea:

```
select name, id, amount from
  (
    (select max(left.name) as name, left.student_id as id
      from #left left
      group by left.student_id)
        left join #right right on left.student_id = right.student_id
  )
```